# ¿int number does not repeat with random.range unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2 numbers that are used with random.range what I need is that the combination of both is not repeated 2 times, that is to say the combination a1, b1 can never be repeated but now I can't get that to happen is for a card game that I have to develop where the same card cannot be repeated neither in the hand nor in the game.

class Meca

```
public List<carta> cardPlay2; //current card combination, each update resets the list
public List<carta> cartaJugada; // current combination of cards, these are saved so that in future 
updates the combination is not repeated

public bool isChange;


if (isChange)
    {

        cardPlay2.Clear();


        int num = 5;
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
            {
                cambioCarta();
            }

        isChange = false;
    }

   void cambioCarta()
{
    GameObject temp = Instantiate(carta);
    temp.transform.SetParent(parent);

    GameObject tem2p = Instantiate(carta2);
    tem2p.transform.SetParent(parent2);


}
```

script carta

```
 public int Num_cartas, PaloCarta;
 public Mecanic meca;

 void Start()
{
    meca = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Mecanic>();
    if(gameObject.tag == "carta1")
        cartas();

   if (gameObject.tag == "carta2")
        carta2();

}

void cartas()
{
    Num_cartas = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 11);
    PaloCarta = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 5);

    carta carta1 = new carta
    {
        numCarta = Num_cartas,
        palo = PaloCarta
    };
 }

[Serializable]
public class carta
{
public int numCarta;
public int palo;
}
```

what I'm trying to do is this

```
private void controlCartaMano2()
{  
    Num_cartas = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);
    PaloCarta = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < meca.cardPlay2.Count; i++)
    {
        while (meca.cardPlay2[i].numCarta == Num_cartas && meca.cardPlay2[i].palo == PaloCarta)
        {
            Num_cartas = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);
            PaloCarta = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 4);
        }
    }
}

 private void controlCartaJugada()
{



    for (int i = 0; i < meca.cartaJugada.Count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < meca.cartaJugada.Count; j++)
        {
            if(meca.cartaJugada[i].numCarta == meca.cartaJugada[j].numCarta && 
            meca.cartaJugada[i].palo == meca.cartaJugada[j].palo)
            {
                Num_cartas = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);
                PaloCarta = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you have any idea how to do it I would appreciate it

Comment: One way to guarantee this is to generate all combinations, shuffle that list, then use the shuffled values in order. Basically it's the same as a deck of playing cards. You have all of the cards, you shuffle them, then you deal off of that deck.

Comment: Of course, what I can't do is check, that is, if one card comes out, the next card cannot be the same as the one that already came out and so on.

Comment: If you generate a deck of cards you only have one of each. If there's 1 ace of spades in your deck you'll never have the possibility of dealing two of them. Possibly your game is different somehow but you haven't explained that well enough if it is.

Comment: It is the same as you say there cannot be 2 identical cards if an ace of spades has already come out, no other can come out

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Fisher-Yates shuffle method. That will shuffle the array, in place. It's then a simple matter of passing over the array incrementally. Here's a generic method that will shuffle an array:

```
static void Shuffle<T> ( T [ ] array )
{
    var _random = new System.Random ( );
    for ( int i = 0, n = array.Length; i < ( n - 1 ); ++i )
    {
        var next = i + _random.Next ( n - i );
        var item = array [ next ];
        array [ next ] = array [ i ];
        array [ i ] = item;
    }
}
```

For more information, here's the Wiki page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle